# Exporting animations from blender to use with Assimp

Tags: blender, collada, assimp

I noticed that if I export my blender project as a obj-file I have the option to toggle "Export Animation" which will make alot of files, one for each frame.
I wanted to use the Collada (.dae) format to export my animations. Problem is, when I load my Collada file it says that `NumAnimations == 0`!

1) Why does a file that is supposed to store animation say 0 animation?

2) When I do get it to work, how to I swap between frames in Assimp?

Answer (score 0):

1) Animation import should work, your problem is probably the export. Have you tried reading through your collada file? Watch for `<library_animations>` and the like.

2) Assimp has no notion of frames. aiAnimation consists of multiple channels (aiNodeAnim) which define transformations (keyframes) for nodes at specific ticks/time. To compute all transformations one needs to interpolate the correct keyframes depending on the current playback time and mTicksPerSecond of aiAnimation.